# sublime text regex doesn't work

Tags: regex

I have a raw data like below, and would like to keep the url links.

```
> http://www.example.com/routes/en/bus-ticket-from-ipoh-to-alor-setar
> data:text/javascript;base64,Ly8gSGVyZSBZb3UgY2FuIHR5cGUgeW91ciBjdXN0b20gSmF2YVNjcmlwdC4uLgpjb25zb2x…:5
> http://www.example.com/routes/en/bus-ticket-from-ipoh-to-alor-setar
> data:text/javascript;base64,Ly8gSGVyZSBZb3UgY2FuIHR5cGUgeW91ciBjdXN0b20gSmF2YVNjcmlwdC4uLgpjb25zb2x…:5
> http://www.example.com/routes/en/bus-ticket-from-genting-highlands-to-singapore
> data:text/javascript;base64,Ly8gSGVyZSBZb3UgY2FuIHR5cGUgeW91ciBjdXN0b20gSmF2YVNjcmlwdC4uLgpjb25zb2x…:5
> http://www.example.com/routes/en/bus-ticket-from-alor-setar-to-shah-alam
> data:text/javascript;base64,Ly8gSGVyZSBZb3UgY2FuIHR5cGUgeW91ciBjdXN0b20gSmF2YVNjcmlwdC4uLgpjb25zb2x…:5
```

I do **`\:5$`** in regex search it doesn't match the unwanted chunk, what's the problem here?

Comment: post your attempts

Comment: @AvinashRaj I bold my attempts

Comment: you have asked too many questions and do not accept any of the answers..you need to accept those answers which helped you..

Comment: @AvinashRaj almost there, but it matched only 1 row

Comment: enable multiline modifier ie, add `(?m)` at the start of your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the below regex to match all the lines which endswith `:5`

```
.*:5\h*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rB1kQ6/1)

Comment: there actually has a space behind `:5`

Comment: seems, `:5` and the link exists on the same line. So remove the $ sign

Comment: what does `/h` do?

Comment: `\h` matches any horizontal whitespace character